# pandasで文字の長さによる抽出

Tags: python, pandas

pandasのデータフレームdfで、文字列のはいった列mojiの長さが3以上のものを残したいと考えています。
mojilen=len(moji)で新しい列を作れば行けると思いますが、新しい列を作らずに処理する方法はあるのでしょうか。

`df.query("len(df.moji)>2")`は駄目でした。

よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: [この回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45071194/9014308)が参考になるかもしれません。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

たとえばマスクを作って処理することができます。

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data={'moji': ["aaa", "b", "cccc", "d", "eeeee", "fffffffff", "gg", "hhhhhh", "iiiii"]})
>>> mask = df['moji'].str.len() >= 3
>>> df[mask]
        moji
0        aaa
2       cccc
4      eeeee
5  fffffffff
7     hhhhhh
8      iiiii
```

1行にも書けます。

```py
>>> df[lambda df: df['moji'].str.len() >= 3]
        moji
0        aaa
2       cccc
4      eeeee
5  fffffffff
7     hhhhhh
8      iiiii
```

このドキュメントが参考になります：[Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)